# Deploy issues with Symfony Project - JWT

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, jwt, lexikjwtauthbundle

I am trying to put my symfony project online by deploying it. Everytime I try to deploy it i got this messages.

> Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.   Problem 1     - lcobucci/jwt is locked to version 5.0.0 and an update of this package was not requested.     - lcobucci/jwt 5.0.0 requires ext-sodium * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's sodium extension.   Problem 2     - lcobucci/jwt 5.0.0 requires ext-sodium * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's sodium extension.     - lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle v2.19.1 requires lcobucci/jwt ^3.4|^4.1|^5.0 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[5.0.0].     - lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle is locked to version v2.19.1 and an update of this package was not requested. To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:     - /app/vendor/php/etc/php.ini     - /app/vendor/php/etc/conf.d/apcu.ini     - /app/vendor/php/etc/conf.d/mongodb.ini     - /app/vendor/php/etc/conf.d/opcache.ini     - /app/vendor/php/etc/conf.d/redis.ini You can also run `php --ini`in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode. Alternatively, you can run Composer with`--ignore-platform-req=ext-sodium\` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
> !     An error occurred during buildpack compilation
> !   Error deploying the application
> !   → Invalid return code from buildpack

Which is weird because sodium is activate, I made composer update and all other things written here

Comment: Sodium extension should be enabled for your specific version. Try to find out which php version is now running in your website for serving your website. After that, install sodium extension. Then finally run composer update

Comment: I am using Xampp, my php version is 8.2 and also my project is in 8.2

Comment: can you check your php modules using command below in cmd?
php -m

Comment: when i do a php -m I can see sodium there

Comment: you are using linux?

Comment: I am using window.